# Calculating Average Document Length with Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, average

I want to calculate average document length for document collection which each document having  3 different fields(filed1, field2,field3)

This is the program to calculate average length when only one field is there.

```
private byte[] normsDocLengthArr = null;
private double avgDocLength;
normsDocLengthArr = indexReader.norms("filed1");
            //norms-Returns the byte-encoded normalization factor for the named field of every document.
double sumLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < normsDocLengthArr.length; i++) {
    double encodeLength = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArr[i]);
    //decodeNorm -Decodes a normalization factor stored in an index.
    double length = 1 / (encodeLength * encodeLength);

    sumLength += length;

}

this.avgDocLength = sumLength / normsDocLengthArr.length;
```

This is how I extended it for all 3 fields.

```
private byte[] normsDocLengthArrField1 = null;
private byte[] normsDocLengthArrField2 = null;
private byte[] normsDocLengthArrField3 = null;
private double avgDocLength;

normsDocLengthArrField1 = indexReader.norms("filed1");
normsDocLengthArrField2 = indexReader.norms("filed2");
normsDocLengthArrField3 = indexReader.norms("filed3");
            //norms-Returns the byte-encoded normalization factor for the named field of every document.
double sumLength = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < normsDocLengthArrField1.length; i++) {
    double encodeLengthF1 = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField1[i]);
    double encodeLengthF2 = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField2[i]);
    double encodeLengthF3 = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField3[i]);

    //decodeNorm -Decodes a normalization factor stored in an index.
    double length = 1 / {(encodeLengthF1 * encodeLengthF1)+(encodeLengthF2 * encodeLengthF2)+(encodeLengthF3 * encodeLengthF3)};

    sumLength += length;

}

this.avgDocLength = sumLength / (normsDocLengthArrField1.length+ normsDocLengthArrField2.length+normsDocLengthArrField3.length;
```

I just want to know whether my implementation of calculating Doc average length for 3 field is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way as the correct way of, calculating average document length, which document having 3 fields with lucene.

```
byte[] normsDocLengthArrField1 = indexReader.norms("filed1");
byte[] normsDocLengthArrField2 = indexReader.norms("filed2");
byte[] normsDocLengthArrField3 = indexReader.norms("filed3");

 double sumLength = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < normsDocLengthArrField1.length; i++) {
            double encodeLengthFOne = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField1[i]);
            double encodeLengthFTwo = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField2[i]);
            double encodeLengthFThree = DefaultSimilarity.decodeNorm(normsDocLengthArrField3[i]);

        //decodeNorm -Decodes a normalization factor stored in an index.
        double lengthFieldOne = 1 / (encodeLengthFOne * encodeLengthFOne);
        double lengthFieldTwo = 1 / (encodeLengthFTwo * encodeLengthFTwo);
        double lengthFieldThree = 1 / (encodeLengthFThree * encodeLengthFThree);
        sumLength += lengthFieldOne + lengthFieldTwo + lengthFieldThree;

    }
    this.avgDocLength = sumLength / (normsDocLengthArrField1.length);
```